# 06 Ford Escape Dead Battery Keypad Entry

Tags: ford, battery, escape

So, the Escape was sitting in the parking garage for a couple weeks with the keys inside and no spare available (don't ask, this is a shared company vehicle with keypad entry). The keypad isn't working. I suspect the battery is dead.

Does anyone have any ideas how to get into the car? I was reading on a forum about popping the hood from underneath or trickle charging from an exposed positive wire. Where can I find an exposed positive wire under the Escape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is call a locksmith, or towing company, even some cab companies are doing this now. They have a kit that will let them unlock the door. It runs about $40 here, call and ask for prices because it can vary wildly.

Opening the hood is possible, if you can get to the release cable but it's very difficult on most cars. Finding a wire to put power to is just to risky unless you know exactly what you are taping into. The positive side of the starter would be a good place for this, but it's going to be a PITA to get too it.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest although not the cheapest method is to call a tow truck. They do lockout calls quite often. The method needed to open the hood without the cable varies. It may require bumper and grill removal.  As @Larry has suggested call a tow service or find a 15 year old delinquent/hoodlum who will have the door open in less than a minute.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and after looking at wiring diagrams was able to charge battery by connecting the charger to the large positive connection on the alternator.  Leave your charger off while making the connection then plug it in with the positive on this wire that is under a rubber cover that can be easily pulled off. then connect negative to ground and set charger to low amperage or use a trickle charger to avoid possibility of blowing fuse in this line.  I did 6 amps and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Ford Escape 2010. My battery is dead and the keyless entry of course does not work. I spoke with the dealership and they informed me that on the cover plate where the handle to the door is is a small hole to the right and bottom of the handle of that cover plate. Insert a small screwdriver or pln into that hole, pop off the cover plate and under that is a keyhole. The rest is easy to figure out. I hope this helps.